# Is this warning in django_tenants still valid?

Tags: django, multi-tenant

In apps.py of django_tenants, I see this:

```
recommended_config = """
Warning: You should put 'django_tenants' at the end of INSTALLED_APPS:
INSTALLED_APPS = TENANT_APPS + SHARED_APPS + ('django_tenants',)
This is necessary to overwrite built-in django management commands with
their schema-aware implementations.
"""
```

My question is: is that still valid?  We had django_tenants installed (in dev) for a few weeks before I happened to see that message in the code.  It wasn't last in INSTALLED_APPS, but it seemed to be working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an app to override other apps' management commands, it should be [listed first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/#overriding-commands):

> Django registers the built-in commands and then searches for commands in `INSTALLED_APPS` in reverse. During the search, if a command name duplicates an already registered command, the newly discovered command overrides the first.
>
> In other words, to override a command, the new command must have the same name and its app must be **before** the overridden command’s app in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

So that advice is out-of-date (this was [changed](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21018) five years ago).

Note that the actual [installation documentation](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#configure-tenant-and-shared-applications) for django_tenants *is* up-to-date, listing `'django_tenants'` first:

> ```
> SHARED_APPS = (
>     'django_tenants',  # mandatory
>     ...
> )
> INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + ...
> ```

So that line of code you found may not be relevant.

Comment: Thanks @kevin.  I upvoted your answer, but due to my low rep, it probably didn't register (yet).